# Center a UIView inside a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I've been facing an weird issue which I have never experienced before (pretty new to iOS). I am trying to develop a blog reader app and I am using a UITableView inside my main View. Within the TableView I have added 1 prototype cell and modified it's height to be somewhat bigger.

In order to create a "floating", "shadow" or "card" effect within the TableViewVell I have added another View which will contain a cover image and a summary.

The problem I am facing is related to the layout that is displayed by the Preview Assistant for Storybords.

Even though for iPhone 8 (xCode 9.1) everything looks fine based on the constraints that I have put in place, for iPhone SE and 8 Plus things look weirdly different even though during the simulation things do not really look as described.

I have watched WWDC Videos, YouTube Videos, even some great tutorials but none seem to go beyond the basics and actually cover this issue that I am facing.

Here is a screenshot:

[XCode Storyboards Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD06k.png)

I made a simplified demo ofthe project which can be checked out on GitHub:

https://github.com/sebastiannitu/ConstraintIssues

I would very much appreciated if seomeone would calrify this issue for me once and for all. I am sure it's just me doing something silly but I cannot really waste any more time with this. I've already invested about 2 weeks in trying to figure this out!

Thank you very much for your replies in advance!

Comment: Seems like a bug in preview. The issue is only in preview when opened using assistant editor, if you simply select various devices in storyboard itself (the one that you will use for applying constraints to various size classes) you will see that your view is expanding as per the frame of cell. So I believe there is no issue in your constraints

Comment: I'm also seeing similar with Xcode 10.1. See my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54524507/view-as-different-device-misplaces-centered-label-within-prototype-cell-in-inter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a mild bug in Xcode, but no big deal. Do this:

1. Change the *device type* in the *canvas*, e.g. to iPhone SE.
2. Switch away to your code, e.g. ViewController.
3. Switch back to the storyboard. Notice that the constraints have now fixed themselves in the canvas!
4. Show the Preview *for that device type*.

So it's mildly annoying, but it does work. Here's the preview for the iPhone SE:

[image]

Here's the preview for the iPhone X:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your constraints setup is fine . problem is with only assistant editor. if you run it in your simulator, View (orange View) will resize currectly.

Here is the screenshot for orange View, when running in iPhone 8s (left) and iPhone 5s.
[image]

i am not uploading project, but if you have problem then let me know.